# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). - Spring Java

Tags: java, spring

I have this service in github https://github.com/felloz/personsService The application compile with no errors but when im trying to access the route http://localhost:8080/demo/persons Im getting this error:

```html
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 11 14:55:30 VET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

The compile message:

```html
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)

2020-05-11 15:05:55.576  INFO 10476 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on lserrano-PC with PID 10476 (C:\JAVA\Eclipse Projects\demo\target\classes started by lserrano in C:\JAVA\Eclipse Projects\demo)
2020-05-11 15:05:55.592  INFO 10476 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-11 15:05:58.173  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-11 15:05:58.198  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-11 15:05:58.198  INFO 10476 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
2020-05-11 15:05:58.386  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-11 15:05:58.387  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2685 ms
2020-05-11 15:05:58.857  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-05-11 15:05:59.362  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-11 15:05:59.377  INFO 10476 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.578 seconds (JVM running for 5.433)
2020-05-11 15:06:14.712  INFO 10476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-11 15:06:14.712  INFO 10476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-11 15:06:14.727  INFO 10476 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 15 ms
```

You can check the code in the github repo, Im new with Sprong any help will be appreciated, im using NetBeans as IDE.

After adding server.servlet.context-path=/demo

```html
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)

2020-05-11 17:26:54.336  INFO 9144 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on lserrano-PC with PID 9144 (C:\JAVA\Eclipse Projects\demo\target\classes started by lserrano in C:\JAVA\Eclipse Projects\demo)
2020-05-11 17:26:54.336  INFO 9144 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-11 17:26:56.926  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-11 17:26:56.957  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-11 17:26:56.957  INFO 9144 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
2020-05-11 17:26:57.160  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/demo]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-11 17:26:57.160  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2715 ms
2020-05-11 17:26:57.612  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-05-11 17:26:58.111  INFO 9144 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/demo'
2020-05-11 17:26:58.111  INFO 9144 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 4.591 seconds (JVM running for 5.464)
2020-05-11 17:27:14.361  INFO 9144 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/demo]   : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-11 17:27:14.362  INFO 9144 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-11 17:27:14.379  INFO 9144 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 17 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

you have `@RequestMapping({"/persons"})` in your controller, so try this link `http://localhost:8080/persons` without `demo`

Comment: Didnt work, i have setted server.contextPath=/demo in the application.propperties file

Comment: yes i noticed, but the running script shows that contextPath is ''

Comment: 2020-05-11 15:05:59.362  INFO 10476 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''

Comment: Yep, thats the problem server.servlet.context-path=/demo didnt fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

after spring 2 , context path configuration has been changed ;

```
server.servlet.context-path=/demo
```

And then try http://localhost:8080/demo/persons

Comment: I changed server.contextPath for server.servlet.context-path=/demo but still getting same error

Comment: In navigator: ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/demo/persons", ok: false, …}

Comment: You explicitly specify ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.DemoApplication"}) yet your base package name is com.example.demo; , you dont need to specify package like this because spring boot automatically consider your main application’s package as a base package , you can delete it or update with right package name

Comment: Moreover to make your api extendable I’d recommend you change your controller class request mapping like RequestMapping("/api") and your showAll method GetMapping("/persons") and use same mapping for all other CRUD methods but change the http method like PostMapping(“/persons”) for add , PutMapping(“/persons”) for update , DeleteMapping(“/persons”) for delete etc

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Jpa, following changes would be needed :

`Context Path` should be set as:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/demo
```

`DemoApplication` Class (correcting base package):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

You need to provide the implementation for your `Repositoory`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class PersonRepository{
    public List<Person> findAll(){
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(10001);
        person.setName("Name");
        person.setLastname("LastName");
        list.add(person);
        return list; 
    }
}
```

To work with MySQL DB and SpringBoot , you can find many example on web. Please follow that. Example : [SpringBootMySQLExample](https://www.dev2qa.com/spring-boot-crud-example-with-mysql/)

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 11 17:27:32 VET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: still having the same message

Comment: in navigator: ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/demo/persons", ok: false, …}

Comment: Updated my answer . Please try this and let me know if you still face issues.

Comment: When i made your changes in component scan i get this error: DemoApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationCon...

And for repository im using this package org.springframework.data.repository.Repository; so i dont see why i need to install jpa

Comment: updated the answer .... If you don't want to use JPA, you need to create bean (`@Repository`) so that it will be registered to Spring.

Comment: If i register `@Repository ` i get an error because i cant use @Repository with that package.

Comment: Hi.. Please see my answer and copy paste it .... I have tried and it is working for me ... You will need 3 changes mentioned in answer. You need to register your repository to spring and it can be done using `@Repository` (stereotype)

Comment: you have to make it a bean .... otherwise use JpaRepository ...

Comment: I made the changes and the json its showed but with the data setted in the code, i want the data from the database.

Comment: server.servlet.context-path=/demo
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud_angular
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Ok .. Now you have working model .. you can now design your repository and service for the retrieval of data from DB - You can use JDBC as well , But I would recommend to use JPA as it is more flexible and provides you various in-built functions like findAll(), findById() etc .

Comment: i gave you a vote because your answer didnt answer my question in 100% thanks for your help.